# How to Search Permutations Efficiently

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, permutation

I am trying to search the permutations of a list of lists, scoring each permutation, and finding the minimal value. I can do so by hardcoding a solution when the length of the list of lists is four. My question is how can I generalize my solution for any length up to 50? How can I avoid writing a series of for loops?

```
answer = {}
l=[[16,5,6],[6,3,4],[5,1,2],[10,1,4]]
lowest = get_expected_value(l)
for x in l:
    for y in l:
        for z in l:
            for a in l:
                if x != y and x != z and x != a and y != z and y != a and z != a:
                     if get_expected_value([x,y,z,a]) <= lowest:
                         answer[get_expected_value([x,y,z,a])] = [x,y,z,a]
                         lowest = get_expected_value([x,y,z,a])

print ans[min(ans.keys())]
```

And `get_expected_value` is defined below:

```
 def get_expected_value(list_minions):
        expected = 0
        for item in xrange(len(list_minions)):
            if item == 0:
                expected += list_minions[0][0]
            else:
                expected += (list_minions[item][0])*(1.0 - (list_minions[item-1][1]/float(list_minions[item-1][2])))
        return expected
```

Comment: The code doesn't seem if it would run. l != list_of_lists. Maybe you could update the example. It's easy to write it with itertools. Just look up the docs. It's built-in in python. The problem is the algorithmic complexity: you won't be able to iterate trough all combinations with such a high length. It's growing exponentially.

Comment: Sorry, sascha. I fixed the second line. As for complexity, that is my main problem. My list could go up to len(l) = 50. That would mean 50! permutations.

Comment: 50! permutations is a lot of permutations to evaluate. Even if you could evaluate one quadrillion permutations per second, it would still take you ~10^42 years to evaluate them all (the age of the universe is only around 10^10 years). The for-loop structure appears to be the least of your problems.

Comment: Exactly, mhum! So, for me, the question is how does one sort through such list of lists in an intelligent fashion? Clearly something is wrong here. Should I be using recursion? Or is there some hidden tool that I am missing?

Comment: @ddcastrodd The only way around this is to narrow your search (i.e.: not examine every single permutation). In order to do this, you will need to describe the get_expected_value() function. There is no way to determine how to narrow the search without understanding the nature of the evaluation function (e.g.: if the evaluation function is essentially structureless, then there is nothing you can do but examine every single permutation).

Comment: Good point. I edited my post. Each sublist contains three elements. The first element is a measure of time. The next two elements are the numerator and denominator of a fraction(a probability). We are calculating the expected time to get through the entire list. We take the first element in each list and multiply it by 1 - (probability from previous list). We are seeking the minimum time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution to handle a list, `l`, of arbitrary length (not that it would always finish in any reasonable time as @mhum points out)
using the same `get_expected_value` function.

```
from itertools import permutations
l = ((16,5,6),(6,3,4),(5,1,2),(10,1,4)) # in general, you should choose a different letter than `l` for variable names, as it can be confused with `1`
print min(permutations(l), key=get_expected_value)
```

The key idea is to utilize the `itertools`' `permutation` generator function to do the dirty work of getting all permuations of the list `l`.
Finally, instead of keeping track of the minimum yourself, you can use the `key` keyword argument of `min` to specify that you want the 
minimum of a given collection of objects (in this case the objects are the permutations of `l`) where their "value" is given by the 
function associated with `key`, in this case `get_expected_value`. So we have: